# Can't get Django-Simple-Captcha to work, posts even when using wrong captcha

Tags: python, django

I think this is a simple issue to solve, but I've been trying for a couple of hours now and I think that my View file is messed up. The captcha shows up on my page, but when i create a post and fill out the completely wrong captcha it get sent and updated anyway.

My views-file:

```
def discussions(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        captcha = CaptchaTestModelForm(request.POST)

        if captcha.is_valid():
            human = True
    
    else:
        captcha = CaptchaTestModelForm()  

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  
    
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.created = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('discussions')

    else:
        form = PostForm()
        captcha = CaptchaTestModelForm()
```

Comment: So you set `human = True` if the captcha is valid, but where do you reject the request if the captcha is not valid?

Comment: Honestly, I just followed the instructions at django-simple-captchas homepage (https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#installation)

Comment: Fixed it by doing this to my view:

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by doing this to my view:

```
def discussions(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CaptchaTestModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.created = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('discussions')

    else:
        form = CaptchaTestModelForm()
         

    return render(request, 'discussions/discussions.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form,})
```

My Form:

```
class CaptchaTestModelForm(ModelForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['entry', 'post_image']
        labels = {
            'entry': "Discuss something spoopy:",
            'post_image': 'Post image (not mandatory)',
        }
```